# Issue adding counter to filter function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

The problem is the counter `multipleitems`.  At this time, this variable is counting all td in the pages, instead of counting only the td that has text inside greater than 1, but the filter to add the .css is working great, it is just the counter that is not working.
The code below is working great to add some css to the specified class on various td.  The code basically filters the td that have the class mentioned, and a value in the td that is greater than 1. What I need to add a variable that counts how many td that meet those requirements.

Thanks in advance for any help...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var multipleitems = 0;
  var s = 0;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a-text-center table-border");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    $("td")
      .filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() > "1";
      })
      .css("border-top-color", "rgb(0 217 150 / 38%)")
      .css("border-top-width", "5px")
      .css("font-size", "20px");
    multipleitems = s + 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to add a class to the `<td>` elements containing the numbers. Then you can target them specifically

Comment: For example `<td class="number">`

Comment: String comparison. Going to see weird things when you compare numbers that are actually strings.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that fixes the use of the `$("td")` (*"all TD in the DOM"*) into the more specific selector, and uses `.filter()` matching the trimmed textContent being greater than `1`

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $(".a-text-center.table-border td").filter((i, el) => +el.textContent > 1).css({
    borderTopColor: "rgb(0 217 150 / 38%)",
    borderTopWidth: "5px",
    fontSize: "20px"
  });

});
```

```css
td {border: 2px solid red;}
```

```html
<table class="a-text-center table-border">
  <tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>5</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, instead of styling using JS, use rather a CSS class for that purpose:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $(".a-text-center.table-border td")
    .filter((i, el) => +$(el).text() > 1)
    .addClass("gt1");

});
```

```css
td { border: 2px solid red; }

.gt1 {
   border-top-color: rgb(0 217 150 / 38%);
   border-top-width: 5px;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="a-text-center table-border">
  <tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>5</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or by using the .toggleClass() method:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope
  
  $(".a-text-center.table-border td").toggleClass(function() {
    return +$(this).text() > 1 && "gt1"
  });

});
```

```css
td { border: 2px solid red; }

.gt1 {
   border-top-color: rgb(0 217 150 / 38%);
   border-top-width: 5px;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="a-text-center table-border">
  <tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>5</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately I may have not explained myself correctly.  The CSS is working completely fine.  What I need help with is the counter, shown as ```multipleitems = s + 1;``` in the formula, this counter is not counting the number of td that has been over 1.  So, in the examples you made (thanks again for those), what I need is a counter that shows me a quantity of "2" TDs that has been modified with the green top border.

Comment: in a few words, I need to add a counter to know how many td have been modified by the filter function.